# MySQL Enterprise backup tool for automation and management

Tags: mysql, backup

What tool do you suggest for automating and managing backups in MySQL?

I manage a 15GB database and I'm looking for a tool that performs the backup procedure as fast as SQL Server does in a similar sized database?

Using the default MySQL tools is too slow, what do you recommend to speed it up?

Comment: You don't mention: Host OS, MySQL version, storage engines used. You cannot get good advice without sharing those details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start)?  Only supports InnoDB and XtraDB though.

Edit: As SaveTheRbtz has pointed out, it now appears to support MyISAM also.

Comment: quote from wiki
"Script provides functionality to backup whole MySQL database instance with MyISAM, InnoDB, XtraDB tables."

Comment: xtrabackup itself only supports inno, but percona ship it with innobackupex which is a controller script which manages it

Answer (score 1):

If it works for 22Gb, it will work for 15Gb. /snark Actually, this will work with any size data set. [Backing up a 22 GB MySQL database daily](https://serverfault.com/questions/9074/backing-up-22gb-mysql-db-daily/13310#13310)

I don't like tools for this kind of thing. I like processes. I script processes, then I have my own customized tool box.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLyog by [webyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/index.php) for my daily MySQL needs.

You can schedule backups to run through the Professional Edition of SQLyog and generally they're tools are a cut above MySQL's.

Answer (score 0):

LVM snapshots from Richard Bronosky's answer will work always. If all your tables are innoDB, you may get away with mysqldump --single-transaction --all-databases.

Dump style backups take less space but are generally slower to restore because the indexes need to be recreated. Pick your poison ;)

Answer (score 0):

It also depends what you're trying to backup against, if you're trying to protect against hardware-type failures rather than "oh-crap-what-did-I-just-DROP" moments, you can get instant (log based) off-server backups to different hardware with [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html), tools like [maatkit](http://maatkit.org) can even make your replication [lag behind](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-slave-delay.html) the master to try and prevent against both types of problem.