# Alternatives to Zmanda for MySQL backups?

Tags: mysql, backup, database, database-administration

I don't have a problem with [Zmanda](http://www.zmanda.com/) but i wonder if there is any better or popular solutions out there other than doing it by hand.

My requirements are:

- Online backups
- The tool should decide to use mysqldump or mysqlhotcopy depending on the database
- Verify integrity of backups
- Send status emails
- Clean old backups (optional)
- Be able to choose between incremental or full backups (optional)

Replication seems to be the "best way to do backups" but I'm not gonna do that on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this does not fully answer your question, but anyway:

- LVM-based snapshots + rdiff-backup or anything else to make differential backup (it's brutal, it might fail you but tends to work for me)
- [xtrabackup](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/21/xtrabackup-07-rc/) - free & open source from Percona. It's young but promising, and provides ability to run live full and incremental backups of InnoDB.

For all of those, you'll need to put some scripts around. I'm ha appy user of [backupninja](http://riseuplabs.org/backupninja), which I use as wrapper for my scripts. backupninja will mail you when things fail, will log output of commands etc.

Take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/8044/backup-mysql-server) as well.

Comment: I didn't knew about backupninja, looks like a great tool :)